# Unity GameObject stuck in the same position while trying to grab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry for a vague title, I'm trying to keep it short.

Anyway, I've been attempting to create a 3D grabbing script that involves the mouse.  For some reason, the GameObject gets stuck in the same position no matter when I grab the ball or where I move my cursor.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grab: MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool grabby;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        grabby = true;
    }
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        grabby = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (grabby)
        {
            transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) + Camera.main.transform.forward * 10f;

        }
    }
}
```

I tried breakpoints, which does nothing.  The variable `grabby` is also changing, so that's not the problem.  The only other issue I can think of is my math.  If it helps, the `Grab` script is placed on the object you are supposed to grab.

Answer (score 0):

In 3D world, the computer doesn't recognize the mouse cursor where you think it is. To solve this, you can use the function **ScreenPointToRay**. for example:

```cs
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
    {
        // Do something...
        Debug.Log(hitInfo.point + " " + hitInfo.collider.name);
    }
```

**hitInfo.point** Will give you the point where the mouse cursor touches.

**hitInfo.collider.name** Will give the name of the object that the mouse cursor touches.

Comment: I'm having no problem with click detection, the problem is with picking up the object.